# How to update data file in exe file

Tags: node.js, express, exe

I am using [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) to compile code into exe file for others to use. I want a front end to input information, a backend to store and process information. For front end, I am using browser and html, for backend I am using express. I need information uploaded to be saved in the exe file so exe file can be shared without any accompanying files. What do I need to do so that my exe can access the snapshot files in assets?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sbm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "run": "start assets/index.html",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bin": "index.js",
  "pkg": {
    "assets": [
      "assets/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "out.js"
    ],
    "scripts": "scripts/**/*.js",
    "targets": [
      "node18-win-x64"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "csv-parse": "^5.5.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

my bin file (runs express and opens browser)

```
const {execSync} = require('child_process')
const {parse} = require("csv-parse")

url = "http://localhost:3000"
execSync(`start microsoft-edge:${url}`)
execSync('npm run-script start')
```

file that is called on npm start (server file)

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs")

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'assets')))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/assets/index.html'));
    const data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"/assets/text.txt"))
})

app.post("/inputdata",(req,res)=>{
    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,"/assets/text.txt"),req.body.inputval,err=>{})
    console.log(req.body)
})
```